# Нужна ли запятая?'

Tags: пунктуация

Перед "и". Предложение:

> Здесь будут моим комиксы о супер-героях и некоторые заготовки карикатур.

Вроде бы одна грамматическая основа, обе части относятся к сказуемому "будут". Значит, не нужно, но не однозначно по смыслу как-то получается. Подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно: запятая не нужна. «Заготовки (карикатур)» и «комиксы (о супер-героях)» — однородные подлежащие, соединенные союзом *и*.

> Здесь будут мои комиксы о супер-героях и некоторые заготовки карикатур.

Обратите внимание на опечатку: *мои**м*** вместо *мои*.